# Spring Batch : Job Terminated in error: IOException parsing XML document from Class Path Resource c:/directory/job-definition.xml

Tags: java, bash, jar, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application packaged as a jar file.

I could execute the jar as mentioned below in the windows cmd prompt

> java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Ddivision=25 -Ddate= -Denv=dv -Dconn=45 -jar demo-jobs*.jar job-definition.xml jobName -next

however the above command fails in the bash shell (installed in windows)  with the following error

**In CMD Prompt:**

[image]

> Job Terminated in error: IOException parsing XML document from Class Path Resource c:/directory/job-definition.xml

[image]

In **POM.XML:**

[image]

Comment: Obviously, the file mentioned in the exception does not exist. Which `java` executable are you using? You mentioned that you are running on Windows. I found that java.exe on Windows requires the path separator to be a `\ `  and not a `/`.

Comment: java path is set, it is complaining about the /job-definition.xml file path.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with _java path_.....

Comment: Ok, I want to run the java jar command using bash on windows OS and I could not do it.

Comment: Please replace image with its text.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? If no, what is the main class you use to launch your job? This is important because we should know how command line parameters are interpreted. Is it a custom one or the one provided by Spring Batch named `CommandLineJobRunner`?

Comment: Yes, we are using spring batch, CommandLineJobRunner is the main class provided by Spring Batch.

Comment: I don't see to what extent this is related to bash. Java is started, and finds a classpath which is obviously syntactically wrong. I would focus on where this class path comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the **path** separators used, in cdm the interpreter is treating this path as an absolute path starting from the root of the drive you are running this.

Git bash however, mangles the provided paths and translates it, adding the current git execution path to the provided path arguments, that's why you see the temp directory in front of your provided path.
If you specify command-line options starting with a slash, POSIX-to-Windows path conversion will kick in converting e.g. "/usr/bin/bash.exe" to "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe".

What you could do is add `//` at the beginning of your path for the bash - `//spring/batch/...`

Comment: $ java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -jar SpringBatchExample-1.0-SNAPSHOT-executable.jar //spring/batch/jobs/job-definition.xml starterJob
ERROR : 09.27.2021:2308 (09.669) [[]main] CommandLineJobRunner: Job Terminated in error: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/batch/jobs/job-definition.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/batch/jobs/job-definition.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: Then try without double //;
But you need to export a var ``export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1``
before running the java command

Comment: This link could be of use:
https://newbedev.com/git-bash-string-parameter-with-at-start-is-being-expanded-to-a-file-path-how-to-stop-this